# Messaging Brokers and Buffers

Tags: java, rabbitmq, messaging

Sorry for the newbie-ish question, but are messaging brokers such as RabbitMQ a replacement for writing our own message buffers? Meaning if we have fast producers and slow  consumers, using a messaging broker takes care of the queueing or do I still have to implmement my own queue buffer?

Answer (score 1):

Your scenario does indeed suggest using a JMS solution, like RabbitMQ. This is a primary reason these queue solutions exist.  If you're expecting a huge bottleneck, with more producers than you can afford consumers, you may have to configure your queues in a more sophisticated manner.  But, you shouldn't have to implement your own buffer.

Comment: So would it be correct to say that using Message Brokers allows one to focus more on other core business logic rather than spending time on infrastructure/framework code?

Comment: yes, if you can buy it don't bother building it.  They have spent all the time building it and most importantly testing it so you don't have to.  Just make sure you are using it in a way that is actually helping you and not trying to fit a solution to a problem you don't really have